# Joining MS Access (accdb) table to Feature Layer in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, import, database, accdb

I would like to join a table from a microsoft access database (.accdb) to a featurelayer in ArcGIS 10.1.

How do I associate tables from that database with existing layers that have a matching attribute?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2373393/125400), there is an ole Db provider for accdb files.

Once you have the driver installed, you should be able [set up an ole DB connection in Arcmap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000452000000).

You should then be able to drag and drop a table from the .accdb file into the TOC, and set up a join to it like you would any other table.

Comment: If you could walk me through the procedure of bringing in a accdb file, i would greatly appreciate it.